# MATLAB java classes

Tags: java, matlab, interface

I'm having difficulty using a java package in MATLAB

Firstly I add my .jar to the dynamic path:

```
filename = fullfile(pwd,'Compiled','SpectrometerInterface.jar');
ls(filename)

javaaddpath(filename);
```

The `ls` returns `SpectrometerInterface.jar` confirming the files existence, and `javaclasspath` confirms it is indeed added.

Then when I request an object, using either

```
obj = javaObject('com.jellymatter.spectrometerinterface.UDPSpectrometer');
```

or

```
obj = com.jellymatter.spectrometerinterface.UDPSpectrometer()
```

it says the class cannot be found. It is definitely in the correct directory within the .jar, and a reduced version of my class is as follows

```
package com.jellymatter.spectrometerinterface;

public class UDPSpectrometer {
    private UDPInterface inter = null;

    public UDPSpectrometer(){
        /* Nothing here */
    }

    public void connect(String addr, int p1, int p2) throws CommunicationException{
        ...
    }

    public double[] get() throws CommunicationException, SpectrometerNotCalibratedException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit: The Diagnosis**

MATLAB's Java virtual machine was to low a version (JRE 1.5) for the compiled java (JDK 1.7).

**Edit: Solutions**

I solved it by compiling using JDK 1.5, but, also, one could upgrade the JVM in MATLAB.

Comment: As a debug hint, can you set the full path of the JAR to the classpath ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat the fullfile function gives the full, absolute, path (i.e. 'C:\stuff\morestuff\whatever\Compiled\SpectrometerInterInterface.jar'), is that what you are requesting, or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: You should distinguish b/n the _dynamic_ class path and the static one , please take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaclasspath.html changing the classpath.txt should hook you up

Comment: @ShmilTheCat Using the static path does not seem to fix it either.

Comment: have you restart MATLAB ? after changing the file ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat yup, and the file is on the static path

Comment: some posts recommend upgrading the JVM (the latest official major is 1.7)

Comment: @ShmilTheCat Tomorrow, I think I will try using the javac option `-target 1.5` Hopefully that might fix things.

Comment: Not that the docs imply it will make any difference.

Comment: @ShmilTheCat I compiled using JDK 1.5 and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch05mat5.html) and set your classpath.txt